# How to split css blocks with regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to split this css file into different blocks. Everything matching /*@- to before the next one is one block. I have been trying to split this css code into separate blocks for a day now with no luck. I really would appreciate any help possible.

```
/*@- XYZ PAGE
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#xyz {font-weight:normal; line-height:17px}
#xyz .fieldset-content {padding:0 20px; margin-bottom:50px}
#xyz h2 {color:#BC0000; margin:20px 0 10px 0}

/*@- ar */
#xyz ul {margin-right:25px} /* This is a normal comment */
#xyz p.top a {color:#bc0000; float:left}
#xyz .spot h2 {color:#000; float:right; margin:0}

/*@- ie6 */
#xyz .spot {clear:both}
#xyz .spot .h2seperator {float:left}

/*@- ie6 ar */
#xyz p.top a {color:#bc0000; float:left}
#xyz .spot {margin-top:80px; overflow:hidden; clear:both}
#xyz .spot h2 {color:#000; float:right; margin:0}

/*@- ie7 */
#xyz .spot .h2seperator {float:left}

/*@- ie7 ar */
#xyz .spot .h2seperator {float:right}
#xyz .spot div {float:left}
```

As an example this would be a single block:

```
/*@- ar */
#xyz ul {margin-right:25px} /* This is a normal comment */
#xyz p.top a {color:#bc0000; float:left}
#xyz .spot h2 {color:#000; float:right; margin:0}
```

This is another block:

```
/*@- XYZ PAGE
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#xyz {font-weight:normal; line-height:17px}
#xyz .fieldset-content {padding:0 20px; margin-bottom:50px}
#xyz h2 {color:#BC0000; margin:20px 0 10px 0}
```

Comment: How do you mean separate blocks? How would you delimit them? Different files, or just more space between the blocks above?

Comment: What are you using to process your regex? Most languages provides a "split" method in their libraries, you just need to call it using your delimiter, ignore the first element if empty and prepend every other with the delimiter again. If you must use match, however, see my answer below.

Comment: @mgibsonbr You are right, that's a better way to do things! I am now using split to do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [non-greedy quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

```
(\/\*\@-.*?)(?=\/\*\@-|\z)
```

Explanation:

- Capturing group `()`, matching:

  - block start: `\/\*\@-` (matches `/*@-`)
  - anything `.` zero or more times `*` lazy `?`
- followed by, but not including: `(?=)`

  - another block start: `\/\*\@-`
  - or: `|`
  - the end of text: `\z`

For that to work, you must enable **multiline** in your regex, so the `.` will match any character, including line breaks.

Working example at [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/9rjzKNJbdy) (*Edit:* modified it a bit to show it's really working; the previous example looked like a single chunk of text)